# Bundling RMagick with Ocra

Tags: ruby, ocra

I'm trying to create a portable version of a Ruby script with Ocra. The script depends upon `rmagick` which requires ImageMagick to be installed as well.

The produced executable works on my computer but it fails on every other computer unless the end user installs ImageMagick manually. I would like to create a fully portable EXE file that runs on any Windows system and doesn't require the end user to install ImageMagick manually.

Is there a way to force Ocra to bundle the ImageMagick DLL files into the EXE as well? If not, how do you create portable Ruby scripts that require `rmagick`?

I'm not fluent in Ruby at all so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the 'ocra --help' output:

Packaging options:

--dll dllname      Include additional DLLs from the Ruby bindir.

In other words, copy the dll to ruby bindir and do:
ocra -dll imagemagick.x.x.x.dll myscript.rb

Comment: I noticed that in the `--help` output but I thought that it only packages DLLs from the Ruby directory. I'll try it anyway and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

you can package external DLLs simply appending them at the end of the ocra command, e.g.

```
ocra myscript.rb rmagick.dll
```