# Compiling Ruby Code Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rvm

I was wondering how you turn a ruby application (.rb) to an executable (.exe). As far as I know you can compile ruby on Mac and Linux with RVM but I can't use them because I'm on windows. So what I want to know is what is the alternative to RVM for Windows.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752249/run-ruby-program-on-computers-without-ruby-installed

Comment: RVM has nothing to do with compiling Ruby scripts. It can compile the Ruby interpreter during installation if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) to create an exe.

This exe-file is a self-extracting ruby interpreter with you code.

After installing ocra, you can start:

```
ocra my_application.rb
```

There are some restrictions/pitfalls:

- You may not depend on additional dll (see e.g. [Bundling RMagick with Ocra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059254/bundling-rmagick-with-ocra) )
- No conditioned requires (all packages must be called by the initial ocra call.).

You can check questions tagged [ocra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocra) to see some details about ocra.

Comment: You can use it as in the command line. Enter `ocra my_application.rb`, where my_application.rb is your ruby programm.

Comment: @user2974834 If this answer is your solution you could accept the answer.